# How to cache axios get method responces using service workers until the responce gets modified

Tags: reactjs, caching, axios, service-worker

how can I cache every single file (big fonts and images) from my own website origin so that it doesn't download same files over and over, BUT I want to make sure that it does download if they get updated.

#### Senario:

- for example lets say i got 3 fonts and 2 images and i use axios as well. i load the page for the first time, and all those 5 gets downloaded.
  now i reload, and all those 5 gets served from cache and none gets downloaded.
  but after a few days i push some changes to one of the fonts and one of the images
  now that user opens the website. i want the service worker to only download the 2 changed files and serve the other unchanged files from cache.

#### Attempts:

- I am already using axios to get some files, and the issue is that it downloads every thing over and over on page reload.
- I also tried using service workers and giving it a cache name. **it does** prevent axios from downloading cached files but if i change a file, i should update the cache name and this will force the user to download everything again (but for once again only) when they come back to website with new version.

any help will be appreciated <3

Comment: this is supposed to be a browser feature, most of time it'll cache it as long as it's a GET call. Check Network tab, things shows up there doesn't mean they are all fetched, most of time they are cached.

Comment: while true, but the behaviour is unexpected, and also the behavior is different from browser to browser, so i guess we should manually control it...

Comment: well, manually control a cache is difficult unless you know exactly when you want to invalidate it. Therefore the browser is making those assumptions for you most of time. If you want to override it, ex. always fetch, then you add a random number after the url. The hard question is the first time, how do you know it's a new request.